# MS Word alternative with math mode

Tags: software-rec, editors

I'd like to know about MS Office possible alternatives for Gnu/Linux with possibility to write in math mode, that is to write equations; at least angle signs and triangle signs.

I am going to send some midterm problems to students. I expected that they will write the answers in MS Word and all be happy.

But now I realize that not all students have Windows, some of them probably are free persons and have Gnu/Linux on their machines.

I also wanted to see who is an author of the document (in file properties) to prevent cheating.

I can not obligate them to write in LaTeX or something similar.

I need something MS Office like user friendly but with possibility of simple math mode.

Comment: You may also find useful alternatives with a search in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I find Latex far more friendly than a word processor. (e.g. I can see why a word is in bold).

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you are sending them. It may help with finding the best solution.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor If we me and you find LaTeX in at least in some cases more friendly it does not mean that we can obligate students to write in latex on exam. The bad is I lately realized the possibility of Linux Users among my student that's why I am asking for suggestions. I have no time to organize something    valuable since the exam is today. It seems I am going to stick LibreOffice.

Comment: Just wanted to add that viewing metadata like the document's author is not a great way for detecting academic dishonesty.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatives to MS Office (and, IMHO, better than it!) are [Apache OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/) and [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/).

But if you do not need WYSIWYG features and need to work with a lot of math equations I'd recommend giving [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/) a try.

Comment: Ok, probably I should explain it above, in the question I will make edit.

Comment: @dr_ https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic specifies _If your question is about:...
Applications packaged in *nix distributions (note: being cross-platform does not disqualify)... then you're in the right place_ Is Apache OpenOffice packaged in *nix distros?

Comment: @K7AAY what does it mean :D

Comment: I used to have once ApacheOpen Office for windows installed and it does not behave well with .docx files. 
Does either Open Office or LibreOffice on linux behave well in their own file extensions with math and also with other languages with different alphabets than English?

Comment: @K7AAY [of course it's available for *nix](https://www.openoffice.org/download/index.html)! It used to be the standard word processing suite for most Linux distributions before libreoffice (which is a fork of OpenOffice, anyway).

Comment: Yes, it's _available_ but is it, as the On-Topic rules specify, _packaged in a distribution_, as LibreOffice is?

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov I recommend you stick with LibreOffice. Although originally based on Apache OpenOffice, LibreOffice has 9 years of improvements and updates over OpenOffice, including speed improvements, many bug fixes, greatly improved MS Office compatibility, and localization in many languages. Apache OpenOffice has very few developers that struggle to make even minor updates and security fixes. OpenOffice is functionally dead at this point. In any case, I think nearly all Linux distributions ship LibreOffice by default anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered allowing some on-line alternatives. Google Docs has a formula editor, but my personal favorite is mathcha.io. I think the Mathcha user interface is both intuitive and fast. You enter symbols and formula elements as text by prefixing them with a backslash, for example, a fraction is entered `\frac`. You don't need to use a mouse at all. Picking individual elements using a mouse, like it is done using a math editor in a typical office application, is very tedious and slow.

Also, maybe you could ask your students if they have any preferences, and then approve a few alternatives based on their input?

Comment: If I could examine them online we have moodle platform for this which controls IP to prevent cheating (We decide not to examine them online since we can not know who has continuous internet connection at home and who has not this option, this is university policy). By the way with google docs or something like this I can not control anything. With editor installed on desktop  I can control some sort of electronic signature at least. and it is little bit hard to cheat, plus time limit makes it possible to do what I need to do I guess.  Let's see what happens I have exam after 2 hours.